# Cannot load and see local HTML file, using vue 3 and composition store

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, store, reactive, composition

I am using vue 3 and composition API and composition reactive to create a custome store

I try to load a simple local HTML file and I keep failing. I cannot load it properly on the UI and I cannot see a proper HTML

My store

```
import { reactive , readonly } from "vue"

const state = reactive({
    fileHtml : ''
})

const methods = {
    loadFile(file) {
        let filePath = '../../components/parts/'+file+'.html'
        fetch(filePath, {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'text/html' ,
                'Accept': 'text/html'
              }
        })
        .then((res) => {  
            return res.text();
        })
        .then((data) => {
            state.fileHtml =  data
            console.log('data store ', data);
        })
        .catch((data) => {
            state.fileHtml = 'An error occured, please try again.'
        })
    }
}

export default{
    state:readonly(state),
    methods
}
```

and my view

```
    <h3 @click="handleClick('Forward', '123')" >click 3</h3>    
    <div id="text" v-html="textHtml"></div>


<script>
import { useRoute, useRouter } from 'vue-router'
import { onUpdated, onMounted, inject, computed } from 'vue';

export default {
  name: myView,
  setup(){

    const store = inject('store')  
    const route = useRoute();    
    const router = useRouter();

    const textHtml = computed({
      get(){
        return store.state.fileHtml
      }
    })

    const handleClick = (part, term)=>{  
      store.methods.loadFile(part)    
      router.push({name:'sourcebook', params: {part, term}}).catch(err => {});
    }
 

    return{handleClick, store, textHtml}
   
  }
}
</script>
```

Issues:

store loads the following and not my actual HTML that I have in my local file

```
<html lang="">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico">
    <title>my-app</title>
  <script defer src="/js/chunk-vendors.js"></script><script defer src="/js/app.js"></script></head>
  <body>
    <noscript>
      <strong>We're sorry but my-app doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.</strong>
    </noscript>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Also, I cannot load the HTML in the UI, even though I tried some tricks like

```
<div id="text">{{textHtml}}</div>
```

but it does not parse the HTML correctly

I am not even sure why to use computed, but for now, that is the only thing that works.

I am a beginner, so please explain what I am missing

Thanks

Comment: ` fetch(filePath` - it doesn't work like that, it should be absolute path, and the file should be in `public` folder. A preferable alternative is to configure the project to use raw loader and import html file as text. "but it does not parse the HTML correctly" - it's not supposed to, use v-html directive. It's possible that this is XY problem. It's preferable to keep the markup in components, then you can import and render them as usual.

Comment: The goal is to have multiple buttons that load different html files in a div. There must be a simpler solution like click button, get html, load it in a div, repeat. Raw-loader sounds good, but I want to examne all simple vue solutions first. I moved the html to public.  In my store I tried `let filePath = process.env.BASE_URL+file` and still the same error. Also in the view, I use `<div id="text" v-html="textHtml"></div>` and cannot see any html now. Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: The simple solution is to store markup in Vue components and load dynamic components where needed. This way it's modular and predictable and problems can be detected at build time. The way you want it is obsolete approach that isn't simple because doesn't play well with modern Vue app. The suggestion is to debug what request is being done and why it doesn't work. The problem is two-fold, first you need to make sure that static HTML is available at requested url, apart from using fetch, check network tab in devtools to make sure that url is what you expect

Comment: You mean using `defineAsyncComponent` with `import` ?  I thought it was only for loading one component once

Comment: `import` can dynamic and accept a variable, with additional complications that dynamic import can bring. Any way t's preferable to just specify `Forward` component instead of "Forward" string where possible with the same results, it will make it much more straightforward, where Forward.vue contains the very same HTML wrapped in <template> tag

Comment: Ok, but at some point more components are going to be added, like Intro, Main. So I need to dynamically load one component according to what button is clicked , after unloading any existing. So click button, load Forward, click another button, unload Forward, load Main etc.

Comment: Sounds like a case for nested route view. Or dynamic component (`<component is>`) which a router uses any way.